# Trusting Secure Sites from Mono

Tags: service, https, mono, cloud, appcelerator

All,

I have a C# ServiceStack console listener application running on Ubuntu using Mono. Within that application I have one service that must authenticate first at Appcelerator Cloud Services (ACS). I have tested the code locally(Xamarin .NET on OSX) and can see the code is fine. Based on the error and investigation using the almighty Google, Mono doesn't trust any secure sites by default.

So far I have tried using mozroots to import all mozilla root certs, and have used certmgr -ssl to import the certs directly from https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com. Nothing has worked so far.

I don't want to put code in place to bypass SSL in order to accomplish this as I think that is a cheap/insecure hack. There has to be a proper way to make this work.

Any and all suggestions appreciated!
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All,

I had it right. I was just missing the reboot which allowed Ubuntu to load up all the certs in the store.

Victory is mine, sayeth the coder...